# Validating the Office Add-in, returning this error ever time

Tags: xml, office365, office-js, manifest, office-addins

I'm tryng to build an Office Addin but now I'm stucked in this validation error for a very long time

````
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="AboutButton.Label">
                  <Label resid="AboutButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="AboutButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="AboutButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.about.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>redirectAbout</FunctionName>
                      <SourceLocation resid="Commands.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                </Control>```

The error is :
````

Error #1:
XML Schema Validation Error: Error found during XML Schema validation.

- Details: The element 'Action' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'SourceLocation' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.
- Line: 263
- Column: 24

```
I'm get this error for all <Action> ... </Action> I have
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `<SourceLocation>` when the [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/action)'s xsi:type is "ExecuteFunction". The resid of the file with the function is specified with the [FunctionFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/functionfile) element, the first child of the <`DesktopFormFactor>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't place both the `SourceLocation` and the `FuncationName` element inside the `Action` elements, for example, see the following example below:

```
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
```

The `FunctionFile` is declared at the top, a child node of the `DesktopFormFactor` element.